# What to set the ipv4 id field to

Tags: networking, ipv4

I'm writing some code which involves putting raw packets onto a network and I'm trying to figure out what to set the id to.

I'm specifically using the ocaml `tcpip` stack.

From what I've read online the `id` field should be unique within a certain timeframe, so should I just set it to a random number?

Comment: Are you fragmenting packets? The Identification field is used to identify all the fragments belonging to an original, unfragmented packet. The field is explained in _[RFC 6864, Updated Specification of the IPv4 ID Field](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6864)_.

Comment: @RonMaupin the packet should be unfragmented, I had a poke round that RFC but couldn't parse an answer...

Comment: @ennox yes having already read that, what should the id field be set to if you are uninformed as to what other flows exist from the system.